# What regular language intersects with 1*0* gives 1n0n

Tags: regex, automata, regular-language, automata-theory

I'm reading a book on automata theory, and the book gives an example that a language with equal number of 0s and 1s intersects with 1*0* would result 1n0n, where n > 0

So my question is, how can I find some regular languages that when intersected with 1*0*, would also results in 1n0n. Is there a way to think about that?

update:
Thanks for the answers! I guess what I'm trying to find is some *regular* languages, so the ones like 1n0n wouldn't work ;)
Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: There are many, many more.  1n0n1*.  1n0n0*.  1n0n(100)*.  I have no easy way to classify them.

Comment: Perhaps the book refers to the set of regular languages 1n0n, rather than the single language 1n0n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B. The language with an equal and unbounded number of 0s and 1s is not a regular language.

<s>As for your question, I don't think there are any more restrictions you can add to *some ones followed by some zeros* to get *n ones followed by n zeros* other than the two you have given.</s>

There are an infinite number of trivially-constructed languages that satisfy the conditions: `A1nB0nC` where A, B and C are any expressions that can match zero width.

Comment: Welcome to the 10k club.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of the question as: "What languages, when intersected with `1n0m`, give the language `1n0n`?" Basically, anything that adds the constraint that n=m.

One example is `anbn`, where a!=b.
Another one is `L = { 1n0n1m0m | n!=m, n >= 0, m >= 0 }`.

Also, as OrangeDog pointed out, `1n0n` is not regular, and since regular languages are closed under intersection, it follows that any language whose intersection with `1*0*` gives `1n0n` is not regular.